# Manage a Pool of Users based on location

Tags: c#, react-native, mobile

I have an app that I want to build but am unsure of what technologies and methodologies to use.

I want to be able to let a user "go online" and share their location. I want to be able to run certain operations based on any given number of online users within a given radius.

I assume that I'll have to be able to continuously poll online users for location, but how do I manage to know and update user's location over time? What technologies can make this possible and is there a pattern that already exists to accomplish this?

Edit to try to be more specific:
Assuming i know how to get location info on the client is there a way for a server to check how many users online are in a range at any time? The only way i can think of doing this is to continually update and store location periodically. Then continually query the DB for users in a certain range.

Comment: This is a little broad, and you may have better luck splitting it up into specific questions. That being said, React Native has a built-in wrapper for geolocation functionality. You won't be able to "poll" users, but you can have the app report the user's location at a given interval

Comment: A more specific question wouldve probably helped.  Im aware of react natives geolocation features. Assuming i know how to get location info on the client is there a way for a server to know how many users online are in a range at any time? The only way i can think of doing this is to continually update and store location periodically. Then continually query the DB for users in a certain range.

Comment: Depending on what language you use on the server, you should be able to find a library that can calculate distance from a point based on the coordinates that you collect

Answer (score 0):

I would use the method which you describe with MongoDB.  Mongo has built-in [geospacial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/) query handling.  Store the location and use the [$near](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#op._S_near) query parameter.